# Using netcat redirection in python to get data, after sending Ctrl C command

Tags: python, process, copy-paste, netcat

I have a python script which send data on port 4097 of my pc. I can get these data using manually netcat with this command :
nc -l -p 4097
Now I would like to do it automatically in a script to check the data integrity. So I launch netcat in python using

> os.system("nc -l -p 4097 > C:\v.txt")

and I try to read my data in the "v.txt" file. The problem is that the data is copied into v.txt at the end of the execution of the command. So I need to send "Ctrl-C" command to the necat process, as I can do it manually,  but I don't know how to do it automatically? 
I am also not sure that my solution using necat redirection to a file is the best way to get the data, even if manually it works.... So any suggestion would be really appreciated! thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the socket module:

http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html

You can set up a simple socket like so:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

This example was taken from here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Comment: Well thank you, ebarr, you have probably a very good idea but I am using IPV6 and I can't find in the documentation the equivalent for  IPV6, Can you help me once again?? Moreover you are using an infinite loop but is it possible to wait only for3 seconds to get the data? Anyway thank you very much!!

Comment: OK I finally found the way to use IPV6 : just replace AF_INET by AF_INET6

Comment: For the 3 second thing you can set a timeout on the socket with `sock.settimeout(3)` then catch the exception when the timeout is reached.